# Xcode archiving iOS app as a Mac App

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I've got an iOS app I've built several times over the last year, and have deployed countless ad hoc builds of with no issues. However, today Xcode has decided that when archiving my app, it should treat it as a Mac App Store app, and not build an .ipa file that I can share.

Git doesn't show any changes to my .xcodeproj files and I can't see any build settings that have been changed. I've got other targets in the project that still build fine, but the primary target I use for distribution is the one causing these errors. Is there any reason why Xcode should think that it's building a Mac app instead of the iOS version it used to?

Comment: I managed to get my app archiving properly again, but I'm still not sure what the cause was. I ended up duplicating the target I was building (that was having the issues), and tried archiving with that new target. No idea why, but that duplicate of the bad build target worked just fine, so I deleted the original target, and I'm back on track again. It's almost like Xcode got confused somewhere.

Since I haven't managed to find the original cause of the problem, I really don't want to mark a solution just yet, since what worked for my situation may not work for anyone else with a similar issue.

Comment: Glad you got it working! Xcode 4 seems to be riddled with these kinds of problems. It's a little disappointing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check if you have accidentally made your Info.plist part of your target. It shouldn't be. Uncheck it in the Target Membership pane or remove it from the Copy Bundle Resources build phase.

(Found answer via this question: [My iPhone app is being archived as "Mac App Archive" and not "iOS app archive"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10411105/60488).)

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks! (Tested this one by adding the info.plist file back to the working target, and managed to duplicate the behavior.)

Comment: Same here. Took me several hours to find this answer. Cheers Johan

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the version number. Select the project in the file browser, then choose your app target and look at the Summary tab. If there is no version number add one and see if that helps.

Comment: That wasn't the case. Version numbers were all there. I managed to get it working, comments above.