# Distribute Archive shows Mac OS instead of iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I created a brand new project in the latest version of Xcode and have been building and running it fine in both Simulator and on Devices plugged into my Mac.

Recently I needed to archive & export an .ipa for someone else to install (still using my developer profile and one of my developer devices), but was unable to do so because when I click on the "Distribute" button on the "Archive" tab of the Organizer window, the top choice is "Submit to Mac App store" instead of the iOS store.

Nothing in my project settings indicates Mac OS instead of iOS, so I'm baffled as to why this is happening.  I've tried duplicating the Target/Product, but the results are the same.  I've also had someone else build the project on a different Mac and they experience the same problem.

Is this a known bug in Xcode and is there some way to get past it?

Thanks,
BT

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/9694038/60488. Though that didn't solve it for me. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have accidentally made your Info.plist part of your target. It shouldn't be. Uncheck it in the Target Membership pane or remove it from the Copy Bundle Resources build phase.

(Found answer via this question: [My iPhone app is being archived as "Mac App Archive" and not "iOS app archive"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10411105/60488).)

Comment: Thanks!  That didn't fix it in and of itself, but I also went over every little build option to ensure they were exactly the same between "Product" and "Project".  Now all is well.  Painful...