# My iPhone app is being archived as "Mac App Archive" and not "iOS app archive"

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm trying to release an ad-hoc ipa using XCODE 4.3.1. when archiving my iOS app I can see in the Organizer that the archive type is "Mac App Archive",
While I know it should be "iOS App Archive".

Now when I'm trying to Distribute I don't have IPA options but mac apps options..

By the way, when I'm running it on my device it compiling and running perfect. 
The Project settings says: "Device family: iPhone"

Any idea's?

Thanks !

Comment: By "Mac App Archive," I'm assuming you mean a .app. If this is the case, (mind you this probably shouldn't be happening) right click the .app and select "show package contents" check to see if your .ipa is in there.

Comment: Ok, there were some warnings the I missed ("WARNING: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file 'Info.plist'.
") So: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1649/_index.html

Did the work + I had to add armv6 and not just armv7.

Comment: Good to hear you resolved the problem. However, you should post how you solved this as an answer and mark it as correct for users who encounter this problem in the future.

Comment: @MDT - XCODE was archiving as mac app and not ios.. now i got it working (see my comment).

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since Guy didn't post it as a proper answer, I will, because I can confirm it works.

Check if you have accidentally made your Info.plist part of your target. It shouldn't be. Uncheck it in the Target Membership pane or remove it from the Copy Bundle Resources build phase.

Comment: Please add more description/image... How to Check if you have accidentally made your Info.plist part of your target ?

Answer (score 4):

If you use Facebook SDK and import their plist file, you need to remove it from the target.